# jqEasy Counter (jquery) - need to have "return" count as 2 characters - how?

Tags: java, jquery, keypress, counter

I'm using the jqEasy counter to countdown characters in a text area.
http://web.archive.org/web/20150317063551/http://www.jqeasy.com/jquery-character-counter

In our implementation though--the database counts a return key as 2 characters while the counter only counts it as one.  Basically the form submission takes the returns and makes them "/n" or something.

Does anyone have a recommendation on how I could modify this code to make the return key register 2 characters in the counter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't unless you change the code of the plugin. Right now the length of the input is calculated in this way (line 56) of the plugin:

```
    var val = $this.val(),
    length = val.length
```

Change it this way:

```
    var val = $this.val(),
    length = val.length
    //returns is an array: if i have two newline characters, it has three elemnts, 3 newline, four elements
    var returns = val.split('\n');
    length += returns.length -1;
```

What you sholud do is iterate over val and find out how many times the return key has been pressed and then sum that value to the lenght. Unfortunately i don't know how to find out "returns" in a string

EDIT - This is what you can do:

```
<textarea id='countIt'></textarea>

$('#countIt').keyup(function(){
    var value = $('#countIt').val();
    var returns = value.split('\n');
    var total = value.length;
    total += returns.length -1;
    console.log(total);//change with alert if no firebug
});
```

This should work, look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D27gs/2/

remember to attach this to the keyup event or it won't work

Comment: To expand. look if the last char typed was the return (keypress.keycode = 13) then add one to the total count

Comment: @Neal:  that gives problem when you delete the character. How would you determine that you just deleted a return character?

Comment: @Nicola -- Well you can compare old string to new string onkeypress of delete or backspace

Comment: @Neal tomorrow i'll check both options!

Comment: I was trying to add an "if" statement as suggested below the var val to look for the return -- but did not have success.  Could anyone please elaborate on what would be needed there?  I'm new to this...Thanks!

Comment: If I put in $('.addMemComments').keypress(function(event){ var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which); if(keycode == '13'){ alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox'); } this shows that return was pressed--but I don't know how to merge this functionality into the script...

Comment: The problem with that approach is that if you press the enter key, you might and up with the correct value, but what if you delete a return?How do you know that?You should have a copy of the previous value...for me it's easier (but surely slower) parsing the whole vallue of the input looking for new line charcters (maybe with a regex) and then adding that number to value.lenght

Comment: how would I accomplish that?  and where would the code be modified in this particular counter?  Will look up what a regex is though...

Comment: Sorry if i didn't answer sooner but i had a lot of work!:) If you still have problem write here and i'll try to help you tomorrow

Comment: still could definitely use any help I can get...!  Thanks!

Comment: anyway, look at the fiddle, it should work the way i'v written in the post

Comment: Greatly appreciate all the help. I replaced the code in the jqEasyCharCounter file with the length code you posted, and then put the #countIt code in the (separate) countervalues file as that's the file that defines the classes (or IDs) specifically. Am currently getting a 'console is undefined' error at the browser...did I implement incorrectly? Have also been curious why the 'length = val.length' bit doesn't need a ; after it where its placed...

Comment: I misunderstood your console.log(total);//change with alert if no firebug section...seems like this is working without that but have to test extensively.  Would have already voted 'helpful' but need reputation 50 to do so!

Comment: Don't worry about voting, if in the end this solves your problem just accept the answer!

Comment: Hmm...I can't see any reason why this code wouldn't work--makes sense to me...but with it implemented--to test if I hit all returns to run the characters out it I'm still over and getting errors at the DB. In firebug the console shows 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, etc. when hitting return--it should only be 1, 2, 3, etc. with the script--correct?

Comment: look here if the result is what you need: every time you enter a characther, you have an alert of the number of characthers, with return counting as 2 http://jsfiddle.net/D27gs/3/